# Conditionals and Loops evenOdd

Tags: java

I am trying to read an integer from the user, then print even if that number is an even number or odd otherwise. I have been told I can assume that the user types a valid integer. The input/output should match the following example:

Type a number: 14
even

What am I missing? Any ideas on how I can get the desired inputs and expected outputs? [Test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHDam.jpg)[3][Test4][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oudip.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class evenOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int even = scan.nextInt();
        int odd = scan.nextInt();

        if ((even%2)==0){

            System.out.println("Type a number:"+ even);
        }
        else {

            System.out.println("Type a number:"+ odd);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have all your variables and order of the flow of your program mixed up. In English this is what you are doing

Prompt user for an integer, call that integer "even"

Prompt user for an integer, call that integer "odd"

If the integer called "even" is divisible by 2 without a remainder then print "type a number" and then the value of the integer called "even"

Otherwise print "type a number" and then the value of the integer called "odd"

Comment: Instead try prompting the user for ONE integer and call it "userInteger", then proceed to test whether userInteger is %2 == 0 and if so print userInteger + " is even"

Otherwise print userInteger + " is odd"

Comment: Based on your question, I think you should review a little bit. Follow this youtube link and watch tutorials 5, 6, and 7. I think that will help you a lot :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtQJXzi3Yns

Comment: Additionally I think you would benefit from using the [Windows Snipping Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/open-snipping-tool-and-take-a-screenshot) which lets you take screenshots of only part of your screen, then you won't have to white stuff, like your name, out :P

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

You only need to read a value from the user once, then decide which message to print based on that value:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class evenOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Type a number:");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = scan.nextInt();

        if ((number%2)==0){
            System.out.println("even");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("odd");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

I have pointed out some issues in your code. Please correct them.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//follow java naming convention and name class as "EvenOdd"
    public class evenOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = scan.nextInt(); //renamed to number
    int odd = scan.nextInt(); //do not need this variable

    if ((number %2)==0){
        System.out.println("Even");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Odd");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Ask the user the question first so that he knows he has to input a number

`System.out.println("Type a number: ");`

You can simply just get 1 input from the user and store on the same variable

`int input = scan.nextInt();`

Then you would just check that 1 input with the if/else and display the correct output

```
if ((input%2)==0){

    System.out.println(input + " is even.");
}
else {

    System.out.println(input + " is odd.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice